# How to wrap response with callback function name in JSONP calls?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

I am doing a JSONP call with

```
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute("src", url);
    head.appendChild(script);
    head.removeChild(script);
```

and i have declared my callback as

```
function myCallBack(){

}
```

So I want to append the response JSON with`"myCallBack({......})"`,

**Is there any way to do it in frond-end itself? with JavaScript**

I can't append the callBack function name in backend by passing `url....?callBack=myCallBack`

I am not using JQUERY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The function call in JSON-P must be generated by the server. If the browser could do it, then the Same Origin Policy wouldn't exist and JSON-P wouldn't be useful in the first place.